# Print to Local Windows Network Share When Network is Down

Tags: windows, printing, ms-dos

I've got an application that sends print jobs to a local print share via a DOS copy:

copy fileToPrint \\myLocalComputerName\sharename

When the network is down it throws an error.  However the share is on the local computer!  Any way to get around this?  I have control of both the local computer and the application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the following article which uses a loopback network adapter to access the local share when the network is unavailable.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210128143915/http://geekswithblogs.net/dtotzke/articles/26204.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It might work if you substitute 127.0.0.1 for myLocalComputerName.